# Doctrine expr()->in() Invalid PathExpression Error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Full Error:

> **[Semantical Error] line 0, col 136 near 'sliders IN(:': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
>   SingleValuedAssociationField expected.**

Problem:

I want to filter my results depends on manyToMany relation but getting an error as above.

Code:

```
if(!empty($filters['sliders'])) {
    $qb
       ->leftJoin('CSSliderBundle:SliderItem', 's', 'WITH', 's.image = m.id')
       ->andWhere(
           $qb->expr()->in('s.sliders', ':sliders')
       );

       $parameters['sliders'] = $filters['sliders'];
}
```

Data:

```
$parameters['sliders'] = [3, 4];
```

I really don't understand what am i doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How i solved my problem:

```
$qb
   ->leftJoin('BRCNSliderBundle:SliderItem', 's', 'WITH', 's.image = m.id')
   ->join('s.sliders', 'sl', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->in('sl.id', ':sliders'));
```

Joined other table with that ids.